# Не получается сделать post request python?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, парсер

Есть линк: https://cabinet.sut.ru/raspisanie_all_new.php
Нужно сделать запрос с выбранными данными из чекбоксов и нажатой кнопкой и получить html в котором будет сформированное расписание.

```
import requests
url = 'https://cabinet.sut.ru/raspisanie_all_new.php'
data = {'schet':'205.1617%2F2','type_z': 1,'faculty': 50007,'group': 52002,'ok':'%CF%EE%EA%E0%E7%E0%F2%FC'} # вот наши данные для POST
r = requests.post(url, data=data)  #делаю пост запрос с уже запрашиваемыми данными в форме.
r.text # вывожу html, <b>но не получаю ЖЕЛАННОЕ РАСПИСАНИЕ, КОТОРОЕ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ СФОРМИРОВАНО</b>
```

Получаю:

```
u'<html>\n<head>\n    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>  \n    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"> \n    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cabinet.sut.ru/css/style.css"/>  \n    <link href="https://cabinet.sut.ru/css/form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  \n    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cabinet.sut.ru/css/table.css">  \n    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cabinet.sut.ru/scripts/jquery.js"></script>                     \n    <title> \xd1\xcf\xe1\xc3\xd3\xd2 - \xd0\xe0\xf1\xef\xe8\xf1\xe0\xed\xe8\xe5</title>       \n</head> \n<style>\nbody {\n    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;\n    font-family: Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica;\n    margin: 0;\n    padding: 0;\n} \nhr {\n    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left center , rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.11), rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.75), rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.11));\n    border: 0 none;\n    height: 2px;\n}\n</style> \n<body id="body" style="background:#fff"> \n<div id="rightpanel" style="background:#fff;width:auto;">\n<form name="frm" method="post" style="text-align: center;width:99%;">   \n\xd3\xf7\xe5\xe1\xed\xfb\xe9 \xe3\xee\xe4 <select id="schet"  name="schet"  onchange="change_usl();" ><option value=0 >\xed\xe5 \xe2\xfb\xe1\xf0\xe0\xed\xee</option> <option value=205.1718/2>2 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 17/18 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1718/1>1 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 17/18 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1718>2017/2018 \xf3\xf7.\xe3.</option> <option value=205.1617/1>1 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 16/17 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1617/2>2 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 16/17 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1617>2016/2017 \xf3\xf7.\xe3.</option> <option value=205.1516/1>1 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 15/16 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1516/2>2 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 15/16 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1516>2015/2016 \xf3\xf7.\xe3.</option> <option value=205.0405/1>1 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 04/05 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.0405/2>2 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 04/05 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.0405>2004/2005 \xf3\xf7.\xe3.</option> <option value=205.1112/2>2 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 11/12 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1112/1>1 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 11/12 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1112>2011/2012 \xf3\xf7.\xe3.</option> <option value=205.1213/1>1 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 12/13 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1314/1>1 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 13/14 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1415/1>1 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 14/15 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1213/2>2 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 12/13 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1314/2>2 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 13/14 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.1415/2>2 \xf1\xe5\xec\xe5\xf1\xf2\xf0 14/15 \xf3\xf7. \xe3.</option> <option value=205.0809>2008/2009 \xf3\xf7.\xe3.</option> <option value=205.0910>2009/2010 \xf3\xf7.\xe3.</option> <option value=205.1011>2010/2011 \xf3\xf7.\xe3.</option> <option value=205.1213>2012/2013 \xf3\xf7.\xe3.</option> <option value=205.1314>2013/2014 \xf3\xf7.\xe3.</option> <option value=205.1415>2014/2015 \xf3\xf7.\xe3.</option> </select><br/><br/>\xd2\xe8\xef \xf0\xe0\xf1\xef\xe8\xf1\xe0\xed\xe8\xff <select id="type_z"  name="type_z" onchange="change_usl();"  onchange="change_usl();" ><option value=0 >\xed\xe5 \xe2\xfb\xe1\xf0\xe0\xed\xee</option> <option value=1 selected>\xc7\xe0\xed\xff\xf2\xe8\xff</option> <option value=2>\xdd\xea\xe7\xe0\xec\xe5\xed\xe0\xf6\xe8\xee\xed\xed\xe0\xff \xf1\xe5\xf1\xf1\xe8\xff</option> <option value=3>\xd4\xe0\xea\xf3\xeb\xfc\xf2\xe0\xf2\xe8\xe2\xfb</option> <option value=4>\xd1\xe5\xf1\xf1\xe8\xff \xe4\xeb\xff \xe7\xe0\xee\xf7\xed\xe8\xea\xee\xe2</option> <option value=5>\xc3\xee\xf1\xf3\xe4\xe0\xf0\xf1\xf2\xe2\xe5\xed\xed\xe0\xff \xe8\xf2\xee\xe3\xee\xe2\xe0\xff \xe0\xf2\xf2\xe5\xf1\xf2\xe0\xf6\xe8\xff</option> <option value=6>\xca\xee\xed\xf4\xe5\xf0\xe5\xed\xf6\xe8\xe8 \xe8 \xef\xf0\xee\xf7\xe5\xe5</option> </select><br/><br/>\xd4\xe0\xea\xf3\xeb\xfc\xf2\xe5\xf2 <select id="faculty"  name="faculty" onchange="change_fac();" ><option value=0 >\xed\xe5 \xe2\xfb\xe1\xf0\xe0\xed\xee</option> </select><br/><br/>\xc3\xf0\xf3\xef\xef\xe0 <select style="width:130px;" id="group" name="group" onchange="change_group();"><option value=0 >\xed\xe5 \xe2\xfb\xe1\xf0\xe0\xed\xee</option> </select><br/><br/><input type="submit" value="\xcf\xee\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xf2\xfc" name="ok"><br/><span id="blok_zach" style="display: block;"><br/>\xd0\xe0\xf1\xef\xe8\xf1\xe0\xed\xe8\xe5 \xe7\xe0\xf7\xe5\xf2\xee\xe2 <input type="submit" value="\xcf\xee\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xf2\xfc" name="rasp_zach"><br/><br/></span><span id="blok" style="display: none;">\xd0\xe0\xf1\xef\xe8\xf1\xe0\xed\xe8\xe5 \xe7\xe0\xed\xff\xf2\xe8\xe9 \xe4\xeb\xff \xfd\xeb\xe5\xea\xf2\xe8\xe2\xed\xfb\xf5 \xe3\xf0\xf3\xef\xef. \xc3\xf0\xf3\xef\xef\xe0 <select style="width:130px;" id="group_el" name="group_el" ><option value=0 >\xed\xe5 \xe2\xfb\xe1\xf0\xe0\xed\xee</option> </select> <input type="submit" value="\xcf\xee\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xf2\xfc" name="el_ok"></span><p>\xd0\xe0\xf1\xef\xe8\xf1\xe0\xed\xe8\xe5 \xec\xee\xe6\xed\xee \xef\xee\xf1\xec\xee\xf2\xf0\xe5\xf2\xfc \xe2 <a target=\'_BLANK\' href=\'https://cabs.itut.ru/cabinet\'>\xcb\xe8\xf7\xed\xee\xec \xea\xe0\xe1\xe8\xed\xe5\xf2\xe5</a>.</p></form>\xc7\xe0\xed\xff\xf2\xe8\xe9 \xe4\xeb\xff \xe2\xfb\xe1\xf0\xe0\xed\xed\xee\xe9 \xe3\xf0\xf3\xef\xef\xfb \xed\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed\xee</tbody></table><br /> \n </div></div></div>  \n<script type="text/javascript">  \n\n function listLoad(data)\n{   document.getElementById(\'blok\').style.display = "none";\n    $("select#group").html(\'<option value="">...</option>\');                   \n    var splits = data.split(\';\');     \n\n    for (i=0; i<splits.length-1; i++)\n    {  var prepareLoad = splits[i];\n       var loadData = prepareLoad.split(\',\');\n       var insertData = \'<option value="\'+loadData[0]+\'">\'+loadData[1]+\'</option>\';\n       $("select#group").append(insertData);                                           \n    }  \n}    \n function listLoad_fac(data)\n{   $("select#faculty").html(\'<option value="">...</option>\');                   \n    var splits = data.split(\';\');     \n\n    for (i=0; i<splits.length-1; i++)\n    {  var prepareLoad = splits[i];\n       var loadData = prepareLoad.split(\',\');\n       var insertData = \'<option value="\'+loadData[0]+\'">\'+loadData[1]+\'</option>\';\n       $("select#faculty").append(insertData);                                           \n    }  \n} \n function change_usl()\n {  var type = $("#type_z").val();    if (type==0) return;\n    var schet = $("#schet").val();    if (schet==0) return; \n    \n    if (type==1) document.getElementById(\'blok_zach\').style.display = "block";\n    else document.getElementById(\'blok_zach\').style.display = "none"; \n        \n    $.post(\'raspisanie_all_new.php\', {choice:1, type_z: type, schet: schet},    listLoad_fac);   \n }\n function change_group()\n {  var group = $("#group").val();    \n    if (group==52327 || group==52328 || group==52329 || group==52330) document.getElementById(\'blok\').style.display = "block";\n    else document.getElementById(\'blok\').style.display = "none";       \n }\n  function change_fac()\n {  var type = $("#type_z").val();    if (type==0) return;\n    var schet = $("#schet").val();    if (schet==0) return; \n    var faculty = $("#faculty").val();  \n    if (faculty>0) $.post(\'raspisanie_all_new.php\', {faculty : faculty, choice:1, type_z: type, schet: schet},    listLoad);\n }\n  </script>   \n </body>  \n</html>'
```

Я должен был получить таблица в html. class="simple-little-table". Но не получаю это в реквесте. Что не так?

Comment: Если не получаете того, что хотели, то что приходит взамен? Ваш запрос выполняется, ответ приходит - то есть POST запрос был успешно выполнен. Если это приложение возвращает не то, что вы ожидаете, то это уже не проблема запроса, а либо удаленного приложения, либо ваших данных.

Comment: В том то и дело, что если я сделаю post Запрос через определенный инструмент, я получаю тот html, который нужен. Но конкретно через python. Я получаю только тот html, который я получаю дефолтно через get

Comment: Попробуйте тогда заменить символы %2F, %CF%EE%EA%E0%E7%E0%F2%FC на что-то читабельное (с помощью urllib.parse). Кодировать строки требуется для GET запросов и requests это должен автоматически делать. Соответственно, для POST это не нужно или это будет сделано библиотекой за вас. Вот еще подробностей по этому поводу - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603928/should-i-url-encode-post-data

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `urllib.parse.unquote` что бы создать обычный текст из URL. `unquote("205.1617%2F2")` на пример.